# Homeplug av frame

Tags: ethernet, wireshark, packet-analysis

I want to check differences between a frame sent by a pc connected to an homeplug and one pc connected directly with the gateway/router. When i sniff packets i cannot see any differences in the frame, the wireshark's filter homeplug-av doesn't show me nothing, I have an homeplug av but seems it doesn't send homeplug-av frames. What Im doing wrong? Any solutions or suggestions?

Example:
Computer "A" connected to router, Computer "B" connected via homeplug.
How can I check that Computer B is connected via homeplug, checking the sniffed packets?

Or
If I connect both pc on the same homeplug, can I study the frames and check some differences with a normal ethernet frame?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HomePlug AV frames are only used on the PLC side. The HP adapter is a bridge that converts them to Ethernet, adapting the framing to the standard Ethernet one.

Subsequently, you can't see any difference when you're capturing on an Ethernet NIC. You'd need a NIC with native HP interface (that is exposed to the OS and to capturing), or an HP adapter supporting capturing which AFAIK don't exist outside the developer world.

Comment: If I connect both pc on the same HP, can I study the frames and check some differences with a normal ethernet frame?

Comment: No - you're capturing on an Ethernet interface, so only Ethernet frames are used.